# want to use the same host and port for ssh session

Tags: docker, ssh, portforwarding

[image]I have **X machine, port yyyy**, and also running a docker container in machine **A, port bbbb**. I want to always give **ssh user@X -p yyyy** to the user, but when the user, do a ssh with X:yyyy , I want the ssh session to be **automatically forwarded to machine A: port bbbb**. (user should n't feel that he is connecting to a different machine)
In future, if I spin same docker container in **machine C, port dddd**.  I don't want user to use the new machine name and port, I want the user continue using x:yyyy but session forwarded to c:dddd. How do i do this ? I want the machine to dynamically x:yyyy point to c:dddd, how do i pro grammatically configure that please? (user needs to have same saved session details in Putty)

For Robert's comment, I added a picture to explain the question with a picture depiction

I resolved this, and added answer for this question below.

Comment: OMG you broke my brain. Too abstract machines and ports. I will draw it to picture in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do the SSH port forwarding, wanted to share with all

Following worked:
ssh port forwarding
logged into machine X

1. Ran `ssh -L 0.0.0.0:yyyy:machineA:bbbb -f -C -q -N user@machineA`
2. able to ssh into the docker from desktop by ssh machinex -p yyyy 
               Note: This command asked us to save the credentials for the first time

   I issued the following Command:

> ssh user@machineX -p yyyy

but I am sshed into machineA:bbbb

[image]

To dynamically achieve this, I ran an Ansible playbook with shell module to run this command in X-machine(from a remote machine)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **autossh** to this type of port forwarding.

I am using same type of approach to connect machine which is firewall protected.

To achieve this, first you need machineA connects automatically on machineX on port yyyy:localhost:22

```
autossh -N -f -R yyyy:localhost:22 username@IP_ADDRESS_MACHINE_X
```

and then from machineX you can connect to machineA easily.

If you configure this with ssh keys, then user don't have to enter password.

Please have a look at blog: [AutoSSH in UBUNTU](https://devopsdevelopment.wordpress.com/2017/07/11/configure-autossh-in-ubuntu/)